# Why is this NPDA?

Tags: automata, pushdown-automata

[image]

I am studying PDA at the moment, and I came up with this question.

The figure above tells me that although both PDA accept the same language, one is non-deterministic and the other is deterministic. I don't understand the reason why the first one in non-deterministic.
As far as I know, the conditions for DPDA is that

1) every transition should have at most one move

2) if $\delta$(q,a,X) is not empty, then $\delta$(q,$\epsilon$,X) should be empty.

However, since the first PDA does satisfy the above conditions therefore I thought it is DPDA.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't use images as crtitical content of your post. This makes your question harder to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics (note that you can [use LaTeX](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands)) and don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first PDA doesn't comply the second condition because $|\delta (q0,a,\epsilon)| = |\delta (q0,\epsilon,\epsilon)| = 1$.